# Formatting a Datetime in an Azure Analytics job

Tags: azure, azure-stream-analytics

I need to insert the timestamp as a column in a Azure Table with the format `yyyy-MM-dd-HH-mm`

In plain T-SQL I would do something like:

```
SELECT FORMAT( GETDATE(), 'yyyy-MM-dd-HH-mm' ) AS 'PK'
```

I thought the CONCAT and DATENAME/DATEPART functions would help me, and I ended up with this, but it is not producing the output I need:

```
CONCAT(DATENAME(yyyy,System.Timestamp),'-',CAST(DATEPART(mm,System.Timestamp) AS NVARCHAR(MAX)),'-',DATENAME(dd,System.Timestamp),'-',CAST(DATEPART(hh,System.Timestamp)  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)),'-',DATENAME(mi,System.Timestamp))
```

`2015-10-12T05:17:37.807Z` is formatted like `2015-10-12-5-17` and I am expecting `2015-10-12-17-17`

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I not sure I understand the question. datepart(hh,'2015-10-12T05:17:37.807Z') = 5 is the right behavior, it is hour Five. Why do you expect 17?
datepart(hh) returns hour in 24 hour format. Below query demonstrates the 24 hour format behavior

```
select
    DATENAME(hh,'2015-10-12T05:17:37.807Z') HourFive,
    DATENAME(hh,'2015-10-12T17:17:37.807Z') HourSeventeen
from
foo
```

### Output

5   17

You can do something like below to always get two digits. At the moment functions that make these kind of operations easier are not there.

```
with T1 as
(
select
    datepart(hh,'2015-10-12T05:17:37.807Z') [Hour]
from
foo
)

select 
  case when [Hour] <10 then concat('0',cast([Hour] as nvarchar(max))) else cast([Hour] as nvarchar(max)) end [Hour]
from 
  T1
```

Comment: Thanks. Is there any way month, day, hours and minutes could be shown as double digit values?: '2015-03-02T05:07:37.807Z' will be formatted as "03-02-05-07" ?? Thanks

Comment: Updated the answer with a way to achieve this.